# Does the AWS Application Load Balancer handle reverse proxy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-application-load-balancer

I am trying to use the AWS application load balancer in my application with WAF support in it. At the same time, I also need support for reverse proxy. Does the AWS application load balancer handle reverse proxy?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if we talk about the same thing, but in my understanding, AWS ALB's are reverse proxy servers.

You add your actual application server(s) in a targetgroup to an ALB listener, and then, external clients connecting to the ALB over http/https will see your application as if it was served by the ALB.

You can add HTTP request filtering to the ALB listener, so you can configure which requests go to which targetgroup, both by domain name and http paths.

ALB's also do SSL offloading, i.e. it handles https handshakes with a server certificate registered in the ALB, so your own application server doesn't need to do that anymore.

Answer (score 0):

No, it can't.

To do reverse proxy in AWS, you can set a NAT Gateway in your VPC. This way, all connections from your servers to a specific IP (or the public internet) will be a single IP.